# Haskell Generator with variable number of inputs?

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

at the moment my code looks a bit like this:

```
gen (x:[]) = [[a] | a <- (someOp x)]
gen (x:y:[]) = [[a,b] | a <- (someOp x), b <- (someOp y)]
gen (x:y:z:[]) = [[a,b,c] | a <- (someOp x), b <- (someOp y), c <- (someOp z)]
```

...
and so on

is it possible to conclude the rest with gen(x:xs) ??

Comment: what are you trying to do? Apply someOp  to a list and put it in a second one? Putting types on your function might help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this recursively:

```
gen [] = [[]]
gen (x:xs) = [ a:g | a <- someOp x, g <- gen xs ]
```

At each step you take all the lists generated by the previous step and combine each of them with every result of `someOp`.

You can verify that this degrades into your special cases by substitution.

Answer (score 3):

For the function you here construct, a more generic function already exists: [**`traverse :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:traverse). Your `gen` is equivalent to:

```
gen = traverse someOp
```